# Spring Boot Security Filter Chain is giving 403 for users with the correct roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Boot version 3.1.4

Spring boot debug logs:

```
2023-09-28T16:24:58.104+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /couponapi/coupons/DOGE
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.first_name,u1_0.last_name,u1_0.password from user u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.name from user_role r1_0 join role r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.role_id,u1_1.id,u1_1.email,u1_1.first_name,u1_1.last_name,u1_1.password from user_role u1_0 join user u1_1 on u1_1.id=u1_0.user_id where u1_0.role_id=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.name from user_role r1_0 join role r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
2023-09-28T16:24:58.367+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-09-28T16:24:58.367+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=doge@doge.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2023-09-28T16:24:58.375+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2023-09-28T16:24:58.377+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-09-28T16:24:58.378+08:00 DEBUG 33556 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
```

I am setting up a spring boot security to secure REST apis. I have three mysql tables: user, role, and user_role which provides foreign key and references to the user and role tables (see bottom for schema).

Mysql database role table has two roles assigned to my two users: "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_USER". I have implemented Spring security UserDetailsService class as below:

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.findByEmail(username);
        if (user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for email " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
          user.getEmail(),
          user.getPassword(),
          user.getRoles()
        );
    }
}
```

The following is what my Security Filter Chain config looks like:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/couponapi/coupons/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/couponapi/coupons")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

If I try to get to any of my protected endpoints using a email that does not exist, I get a 401 which is expected.
But if I give a correct email and password to authenticate, I receive 403, regardless of whether the authenticated user is having the ADMIN or USER role.

I have entity classes for the User and Role which are mapped as many to many with the following mysql schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USER_ROLE(
USER_ID int,
ROLE_ID int,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES user(id),
FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
REFERENCES role(id)
);

insert into user(first_name,last_name,email,password) values ('doge','doe','doge@doge.com','__password__');
insert into user(first_name,last_name,email,password) values ('cate','doe','cate@cate.com','__password__');

insert into role values(1,'ROLE_ADMIN');
insert into role values(2,'ROLE_USER');

insert into user_role values(1,1);
insert into user_role values(2,2);
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: They don't have authorities as the logging clearly shows.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was able to make it work by removing the lombok annotation, but I am not sure how and why that fixed it

Comment: Using `@Data` with `@Entity` is bad idea anyway (see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).

Comment: your true error is being swallow as your logs show that something goes wrong and an exception is thrown. This exception is caught and spring redirects you to the spring boot error endpoint `/error` but you have not added any request matcher for it so spring security responds with a 403 because its forbidden for you to access `/error` its litteraly the first thing when you read about error handling in spring boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.4/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling if you enable TRACE logging you can prolly see the correct error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work, by removing the @Data lombok annotation on my Role entity class, and instead manually writing a getter and setter for id, name fields, but not on the users field.

But the question now is, why and how did that fix it?

```java
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: well don't think it is related to lombok. you should somehow fix it in other area ...